# How to read a csv file row by row and create a table?

Tags: tables, csv

I have a problem reading my rows from the .csv database. Separated by commas every key.
So, here is my .csv:

```
id,term,description
1,"system","name"
2,"syst2","description system"
3,"syst3","no name"
```

And here is my table where I put it (I made it MVE):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{ICD}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}   %для таблиц со слиянием столбцов и строк
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}      %для таблиц с заданной шириной столбца
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{datatool} %для работы с базами данных

\begin{document}
\newpage
\DTLloaddb{myDB}{terms.csv} %работа с базой данных
 \begin{DTLenvforeach}{myDB}{\id=id,\Ter=term,\desc=description}
 
 \vspace{\fill}
 \end{DTLenvforeach}

\section{Термины, определения и сокращения }
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
         no& Термин/сокращение & Описание, расшифровка  \\
         \hline
         \id &  \emph{\T} &  \emph{\TA} \\
         \hline
        % 2 &  \emph{\TB} &  \emph{\TC} \\
        \id&\emph{\Ter} & \emph{\desc}\\
         \hline
        % 3 & \emph{\TD} & \emph{\TE} \\
          2&\emph{\Ter} & \emph{\desc}\\
         \hline
         4 & \emph{\TF} & \emph{\TG}  \\
         \hline
         5 & \emph{\Th} & \emph{\TI}\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}


\endinput
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the complexity of your CSV file. For simple csv files like in your question, using package [`csvsimple-l3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) would be the simplest way to go. See the following example.

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.csv}
id,term,description
1,``system'',``name''
2,``syst2'',``description system''
3,``syst3'',``no name''
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{sample.csv}
\end{document}
```

It generates:

[image: 1]

---

Note that I have changed the normal quotations, i.e., `Here is some "text".` with the LaTeX-friendly quotations, i.e., ``` Here is some ``text''. ```

Comment: I need to use .csv file without overwriting the contents of the database in the whole .tex program

Comment: thanks for helpful advice about different libraries usage, I think I can use these two libraries '\usepackage{csvsimple} and \usepackage{makecell}' . So, inside the table I will use such construction  \csvreader[late after line=\\\hline] {state.csv}

Comment: @Programmer1988 You can definitely do that. I used the `filecontents` environment just to save some time in saving another csv file. I just copy-pasted the content of your csv and with that environment it got automatically generated. I use `overwrite` parameter so that my edits get overwritten on that file directly. You don't need to use it if you find it unnecessary.

Comment: many thanks for support and answer!

Comment: That's my pleasure :)